# Remove ** from string

Tags: r, string

I have strings in a column of a dataframe, some of which contains ** (e.g, `75 state street**`) and I want to remove those, (i.e., `75 state street`). I tried the following:

```
gsub("*", "", Name)
gsub("\\*", "", Name)
gsub("[\\*]", "", Name)
```

But none of these are working. What is the correct way to do this? I am not so good with regex, so I may be missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: surprised that your second regex (`"\\*"`) didn't work?  It works for me ...

Comment: Expanding on what @BenBolker says, to me, your second and third regex worked for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little variant:

```
gsub("\\*+","", Name)
```

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can just do:

```
sub("**", "", "75 state street**", fixed = TRUE)

[1] "75 state street"
```